# jQuery- find in multiple elements specific class & add to the first, second different classes

Tags: jquery, each, css-selectors

I have in a div Container some News Articles with and without images. Now want to add for each article without image a different class. If there is an image, the image is wrapped with `<div class="news-img-wrap"></div>`. Articles with no images don't have this `div`. So i try this

```
$('.news-list-view article .content-background').each(function () {
   if ($(this).find('.news-img-wrap').length) {
      $(this).addClass('colored-box-red ');



   } else {
      $(this).addClass('default-box');
   }
});
```

This code works fine for all articles with image get the extra class.
My Question is how i can give each article with image an different extra class "first,second,third"

My example till now.http://jsfiddle.net/b9JuT/

thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: are you trying to add three more classes to each div containing an element, or add different classes to some of the divs containing elements in a specific pattern or order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a count and create unique classes on the fly by incrementing it each time a class is added:

```
var classCount = 1;

$('.news-list-view article .content-background').each(function () {
if ($(this).find('.news-img-wrap').length) {
    $(this).addClass('colored-box-red ').addClass('img-' + classCount);
     classCount++;
} else {
    $(this).addClass('default-box');
}
});
```